# Identify the set of strings of odd length over {a, b} that contain the substring bb

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

> > I need identify the set of possible strings of odd length over $\sum$ (the alphabet) {*a, b*} that contain the substring *bb*.

This is new material and a new concept to me and would really appreciate any perspective on how to go about solving this (with an explanation of course).

The only ways I see possible of solving this is through a mathematical proof by *induction* approach? Or by generating a *regular-expression* that defines this language (which is also something I feel is a bit ambiguous).

Comment: A regular expression unambiguously defines a language.

Comment: Yes of course; I am saying that the process of generating a regular expression that defines a language is not clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: You could start by finding a regular expression for the strings that contain the substring $bb$, irrespective of their length: the simplest is

$$(a+b)^*bb(a+b)^*\;.\tag{1}$$

Each of the subexpressions $(a+b)^*$ matches the set of **all** strings over $\{a,b\}$, so $(1)$ matches anything of the form $ubbv$ with $u,v\in\Sigma^*$, i.e., any string that has the substring $bb$ in it somewhere.

But we want only the strings $ubbv$ of odd length. Now $|uv|=|ubbv|-2$, so $ubbv$ has odd length if and only if $uv$ has odd length. And $|uv|=|u|+|v|$, so we want to generate all pairs of strings $u$ and $v$ such that $|u|+|v|$ is odd. That happens precisely when one of $|u|$ and $|v|$ is odd and the other is even.

- Explain why the regular expression $$(aa+ab+ba+bb)^*\tag{2}$$ matches precisely the strings over $\Sigma$ that have even length.
- Find a regular expression that matches precisely the strings over $\Sigma$ that have odd length; you may find it helpful to start with $(2)$ and modify or add to it.
- Use the previous results to get a regular expression that matches precisely the words $ubbv\in\Sigma^*$ such that $|u|$ is odd and $|v|$ is even.
- Do the same for words $ubbv$ such that $|u|$ is even and $|v|$ is odd.

Now put the pieces together to get a regular expression that matches precisely those words over $\Sigma$ that contain the substring $bb$ and have odd length.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Just so I am sure, are we guaranteeing ubbv will have odd length by stating the cardinality of |uv| = the cardinality of |ubbv| - 2? And in regards to your definition of the regular expression that matches strings that have even length; is the reason because no matter what, whenever we enter into that 'kleene star' we will always be grabbing strings of length 2 (resulting in all evens)?

Comment: Also, when you define (1), would I be correct in saying the '+' can also be thought of as the union of a and b?

Comment: @taylor.tackett: To answer the last question first: There are several variants of regular set notation; I’ve seen $\cup$, $\lor$, and $\mid$ used where I used $+$. Whichever symbol is used, I think of it as **or**: $a+b$ matches $a$ **or** $b$. This isn’t precisely a union, but it’s the same idea, so you’re probably interpreting the $+$ correctly.

Comment: @taylor.tackett: We want $ubbv$ to have odd length. Because $|ubbv|=|uv|+2$, $|ubbv|$ and $|uv|$ are either both odd or both even. Thus, ensuring that $uv$ has odd length is exactly what’s needed to ensure that $ubbv$ has odd length. \\ Yes, since each of $aa,ab,ba$, and $bb$ has even length, concatenating any number of them via the star results in a string of even length. The other important point here is that *every* string of even length is a concatenation of these four substrings: just chop it up into pairs, and each pair *must* be one of these four things, because no other pairs exist.

Answer (score -3):

A regular expression to generate strings of odd lengths:

```
         (a+b)+a|b(aa+ab+ba+bb)*
```